How computer communicates with a display device like monitor?
I have a series of questions:How does a cpu communicate with monitor?
Where is the display related information stored?
How does it know which part of the screen to update?
It would be of great help if someone could explain this in detail or provide some resources from where I can learn about this.
I'm struggling to find the right resources please help me.

There are So many books and resources about this.

@SolarMike could you suggest me some?Also I'm unable to find the exact keywords and topic under my question falls. Thanks in advance!

It might help you to start back at the beginning with analog TV. Technology Connections channel on YouTube is excellent. See https://youtu.be/l4UgZBs7ZGo.

@Transistor that is gold,thanks a lot !!

vimalathithan17 - This is a cross-site duplicate of the same question you asked on Computer Science.SE. Please don't repeat questions across SE sites as it duplicates effort & wastes people's time repeating the same work. See this FAQ article. || Interested site members can work on the topic at that CS.SE link. || Also, the question is too broad. Depending on the level of detail you want, a good answer could be a book chapter or more in length. || SE questions should be a reasonable scope. TY

@SamGibson sure I won't repeat it. Could you suggest some resources to learn about this a book or a chapter?
